# How to report a deceptive in app purchase

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Hoe do you go about reporting a deceptive in app purchase to apple? For example if an app has a purchase that claims to remove ads but it does not remove them as described.

What I mean is the app has 3 types of ads. one is a forced ad that shows from time to time. Another is an ad that is required in order to progress in the game, for example in order to unlock the next item that can be purchased. And the final is an ad that can be watched for a reward.

I am currently on a device with ios 13 beta so I am unable leave a review and there appears to be no way to report a problem with the app from the app store on the device

Answer (score 2):

When you open the App Store, near the top on the right is a link to support. This takes you to iTunes support where you can search or submit a question.  I searched on your question and found the following:

> Contact the iTunes Store Customer Service department using the form on
>   their   Support page (select the category and subcategory closest to
>   the issue you're reporting and you'll find either an "Express Lane"
>   button - just follow the instructions to get to the contact form - or
>   an "Email Us" button) and explain your situation to them.

Answer (score 2):

Apple app store support for third-party apps (not officially designed by Apple) is virtually nonexistent.

The only thing I ever found on reporting scams in the App Store is their "Report A Problem" link (https://reportaproblem.apple.com) which allows you to report bad purchases or scams within 90 days of the original charge.

Other than that, there is no fraud-protection, refunds, or third-party app support. Apple's website makes it virtually impossible to report anything out of purchases in the 90-day context. There's no link for reporting App Store rule violations. Caveat emptor - let the buyer beware. Assume that any microtransaction in an app can and will scam you, and don't assume Apple will help you out because they don't in my experience. (That's also the reason why I largely stopped buying apps on the App Store in protest of their horrendously bad and limited options for reporting problems.)